# Getting HTML span element to use the rest of td's width

Tags: html, css

I would like the span element width to be the rest of td's width.

Here is a very simple example. In other words, now I have some code, but the span element will be too wide. It will go over the latest td element.

Here is the HTML code which has some basic CSS code, too. I'm not allowed to modify the basic strucuture of this table. All I want to do is modifying my span element.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30px;">1</td>
    <td><a href="go.htm">Go</a> <span style="display:inline-block;width:100%;background-color:black;">to...</span></td>
    <td>#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How should I modify the span element to get it use the rest of the td but no more?

Comment: there's multiple solutions to this but flexbox will make your life much easier , consider giving it a try

Comment: Here is my own solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42748626/5833180

Comment: as I said it is very much possible without flexbox, but with flex you wouldn't have to hardcode margins and width so it's future proof since it would work with different font family/size, different content (word length) so yeah it sure can be done without it but you wont get that pixel perfect fill and fit!

Comment: @MaherFattouh Thanks, I see your point. At the moment I need a cross-browser solution, so I would not prefer using flex this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own solution to my problem. This is the best way which I was able to find out.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30px;">1</td>
    <td style="padding-left:65px;"><a href="go.htm" style="position:absolute;left:45px;margin-top:-2px;">Go</a> to...</td>
    <td>#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

this could be achieved using flex box

```css
td div {
  display: flex;
}

td span {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30px;">1</td>
    <td>
      <div>

        <a href="go.htm">Go</a> <span style="background-color:black;">to...</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! How about without using flex?

Comment: since you don't know the width of the "a" tag then using javascript would be required

Comment: You could say that the width of the "a" tag is 65 px. It is the maximum.

Comment: having max-width:65px means the width changes between 0 and 65px so its stll unknown.. why can't you use flex?

Comment: Because of Internet Explorer.